# Angular ui-select not selecting the option that the ng-model is set to on initializing the controller

Tags: ui-select

```
<select
    ng-model="SamplePagesCtrl.selectedRange"
    options="range.value as range.label for range in      SamplePagesCtrl.rangeOptions"
    viq-label="Range">
</select>
```

javascript

controller.selectedRange = 'TODAY';

so the options look like this {value : 'TODAY', label : 'Today"} etc.

on loading the page the dropdown does not select the option. i double checked that the model is the correct value and even put a watcher on the model. when i select another option the model is changed.

so that means the model that i'm referring to is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `rangeOptions` structure, you must used an array instead of an object, try this:

```
rangeOptions = [{value : 'TODAY', label : 'Today"}];
```